# ASP Net - How to open up a form in a new window in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on ASP.net using VB.net. I need to load a page in a new window on button click.
Can someone suggest the code for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need a postback to the new window, then this:

```
<input type="button" value="buttonName" onclick="window.open('[page]')" />
```

OR

```
<asp:button text="buttonName" onclientclick="window.open('[page]');return false;" />
```

Else you will have to set the 'target' attribute of the form to something e.g. "_blank"

Comment: how do I close the parent form on button click?

Comment: In the page loaded at thenew window, you can add window.parent.close() and there's likely to be a browser prompt. Are you sure you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using this javascript within the Button.Attribute.Add method:

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('mySite'); return false;");
```

You can remove the 'return false' if you want the button to continue its postback.

You can customise the javascript further. Parameter information can be found here:
http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You should do that with javascript, for example using `window.open()`.